# Formatting thesis

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, thesis

I am having a problem in the beginning of chaper 1 with the vertical spacing of the initial text. The chapter 2 and remaining chapers are equal, but chapter 1 seems to start more in the top. I would appreciate any help or tip to solve this issue, thanks.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, font=bf, labelfont=bf, textfont=bf, labelsep=endash, format=hang,justification=raggedright}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple, font=bf, labelfont=bf, textfont=bf, labelsep=endash, format=hang,justification=raggedright}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=16.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\lhead{Incorporating Road Safety into Pavement Management \\ Rita Justo Silva} 
\rhead{Thesis Project \\ \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{\hspace{0.2cm}-}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{\hspace{0.2cm}-}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylen}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{firstbib}
\booltrue{firstbib}
\preto{\bibitem}{\ifbool{firstbib}{\thispagestyle{fancy}\setbool{firstbib}{false}}{}}\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \pagenumbering{roman}           % roman page numbing (invisible for empty page style)
    \pagestyle{empty}               % no header or footers

\input{titlepage}

\input{abstract}

\clearpage

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\listoftables

    \chapter{Introduction} \thispagestyle{empty}

       \pagestyle{fancy}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}\usepackage{multirow} \input{Chapters/1_introduction}

       \clearpage
       \phantomsection

    \chapter{Literature Review} \thispagestyle{empty}

        \input{Chapters/2_literature_review}

       \clearpage
       \phantomsection
.....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your editing, but can you solve my problem? I don't understand why latex does that...

Comment: You get the warning `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 27.18335pt.` Add `headheight=27.2pt` to the options for `geometry`.

Comment: I solved the issue doing \vspace*{-0.3cm}.

Comment: Why doing it the wrong way?

Comment: @ritajustosilva: `\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}` is the preferred way (or setting this as option in `geometry` package, which you use anyway here!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I am a new user of latex and sometimes I fix things in a wrong way... Thank you for helping me, it work perfectly :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments